# Linux permissions with Firefox

Tags: linux, permissions

I have /usr/bin/firefox with

```
permissions : rwxrwxrwx
owner : root
group : root
```

I am 'user' on my system.

When I run firefox, and do a:

```
ps -ef | grep firefox
```

I find that the owner of the process is 'user'.

Now, when this firefox process tries to open a html file with

```
permissions : ---rwxrwx
owner : root
group : root
```

should it be able to read the file?

Moreover, to render this file on the screen, does the browser need read or execute permission?

Comment: Firefox should not be world-writable; anybody can overwrite with their choice of malicious program.

Answer (score 2):

It should be able to read the file. You are probably neither root user nor root group, so your permissions are the "other" set, which is the last 3 characters. You have an 'r', so you can read.

To render the file. the browser needs just read permissions.

Comment: More precisely, to _read_ the file, the browser needs read permissions. To _render_ it, I think it needs write permissions on your system's graphics device (but if that were a problem, you wouldn't be able to see anything on the screen!)

Answer (score 1):

The UID (what you are calling "process owner") is what counts when opening files - since you say Firefox is running as "user", that's the user we use when determining if the Firefox process has access to something.

If we have a file:

```
---rwxrwx owner : root group : root
```

Since we are "user", and "user" is not the owner or the group, we are the other. Read permission is get for other, and thus, we can read this file.

Finally, you note that /usr/bin/firefox is:

```
rwxrwxrwx owner : root group : root
```

...this is typically incorrect. As another poster noted, since I have write access, I can overwrite firefox with anything I want - potentially even another program! Typically, things in /usr/bin are rwxr-xr-x, so that only root can read/write them. (There are a few exceptions.)

Answer (score 0):

Anyone including root is able to open an html file having the unusual permissions "---rwxrwx root root"

The first "---" are indeed useless in that case as root is not subject to access restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that, if firefox *the file* is owned by root, but firefox *the process* is owned by "user", and your permissions are none for the owner, then firefox will work fine when running as root, since access restrictions don't count, but firefox won't be able to do much of anything running as "user".

More to the point: "everyone" will be able to do whatever they want to the file or the process, but the *owner* (if he's not root) won't be able to do anything at all.

I could be wrong, though...

Answer (score -1):

It is also important to mention the permissions on the directory in which the file resides. In order to be able to access the directory, the user should have an execute permission on it.